# C++ automatically choose correct overloaded function based on argument type

Tags: c++, overloading, sfinae, overload-resolution

I'm creating a interface `OutputItem<T>` for writing to a json object. I want there to be different modes of writing to the json object, thus I have provided a overloaded method `json_serialize` which takes a `SetConstructType*` or `AppendConstructType*` argument, which are derived structs of `ConstructType`. Upon construction of `OutputItem<T>`, I want the user to pass a `ConstructType*` in the constructor of `OutputItem<T>` which will be saved to `const ConstructType* constructType` to be used later to automatically pick the right overloaded type when the public method `void write(nlohmann::json& json)` is called.

However I'm getting a error:

> 'void OutputItem::json_serialize(const SetConstructType *,nlohmann::json &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const ConstructType *' to 'const SetConstructType *'

Can someone show me the correct way of achieving this automatic overload resolution? Additionally is this a example of a SFINAE design?

Thanks

```
struct ConstructType {

protected:
    ConstructType() {}
};
struct SetConstructType : public ConstructType {};
struct AppendConstructType : public ConstructType {};

static SetConstructType*  SetConstruct;
static AppendConstructType*  AppendConstruct;

template<typename T>
struct OutputItem {

    OutputItem(const std::string& cgroupName, const std::string& citemName, const T& cdata, ConstructType* cconstructType) 
: itemName(citemName), groupName(cgroupName), data(cdata), constructType(cconstructType) {}
    
    const std::string itemName;
    const std::string groupName;
    const T data;

    const ConstructType* constructType;

    void write(nlohmann::json& json) {
        json_serialize(constructType, json);
    }

private:

    void json_serialize(const SetConstructType*, nlohmann::json& json) {
        json[groupName][itemName] = data;
    }

    void json_serialize(const AppendConstructType*, nlohmann::json& json) {
        json[groupName][itemName].push_back(data);
    }
};
```

Usage

```
    json response;

    OutputItem<int> item1("testgroup", "item1", 2, AppendConstruct);
    OutputItem<int> item2("testgroup", "item2", 2, SetConstruct);
    item1.write(response);
    item2.write(response);
```

Comment: Overload resolution happens at compile time, based on the compile-time type. You can't select an overload based on the runtime type.

Comment: Please post the error message. Also, perhaps make clear in the question that you are using the nlohman json librarry

Comment: Oops - I commented out the line causing the error. xD

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way. At runtime, the equivalent to overload resolution is virtual method dispatch. Are you familiar with virtual class methods?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thats strange, I'm also using MSVC C++17. I've added the error message now too.

Comment: I edited my comment.

Comment: Would you be okay with moving `AppendConstruct` into the template parameters, so you would call it like `OutputItem<int, AppendConstruct> item1("testgroup", "item1", 2);`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Unfortunately not. I will have many different `ConstructTypes` and OutputItem will need to be stored in a variant with a list of acceptable types. Adding a extra template parameter would force me to declare the OutputItem types n times for each different ConstructType.

Comment: It seems `ConstructType` should have virtual method, such as `void add(json&, int)`. You have indeed template `T` and there are no template virtual method, but json only supports limited number of types.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't select an overload at runtime, you need a more dynamic mechanism.
It is difficult to solve this with your external hierarchy since you can't have virtual templates.

One alternative would be to redirect through a member function pointer instead.

Illustration (without all your parameters and data):

```
enum class Construction
{
    Set,
    Append
};

template<typename T>
class OutputItem {
public:
    OutputItem(Construction kind): construct(select(kind)) {}
    void write() { (this->*construct)(); }

private:
    using ConstructType = void (OutputItem::*)();
    ConstructType construct;
    
    ConstructType select(Construction c)
    {
        static ConstructType cs[] = { &OutputItem::setConstruct, 
                                      &OutputItem::appendConstruct };
        return cs[static_cast<int>(c)];
    }
    void setConstruct() { std::cout << "Set\n"; }
    void appendConstruct() { std::cout << "Append\n"; }
};

//...
int main()
{
    OutputItem<int> o0(Construction::Set);
    o0.write();
    OutputItem<std::string> o1(Construction::Append);
    o1.write();
}
```